# sed match one condition but not the other

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I'm trying to match `"text"},` but not `"text"}},`
Specifically: `}, vs }},`

How could I write this using sed?

I've tried: `s/\},`

Comment: Hi, is the problem solved or do you need more help with it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to consider `perl` then it is pretty straight forward using a negative lookbehind assertion.

```sh
cat file
text"}, but not "text"}}, foobar"}, but not "xyz123"}},

perl -pe 's/(?<!})},/##/g' file
text"## but not "text"}}, foobar"## but not "xyz123"}},
```

Here `(?<!})` is negative lookbehind that will fail the match if we have a `}` before `},`.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that `}},` contains `},`. Try `/"},/`

Answer (score 0):

I havent tested this, but try:

```
sed -i "/\b\("text"},\)\b/d" sourceFileName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
sed -E 's/(^|[^}])\},/\1/g' file > newfile
```

Here,

- `-E` enables a POSIX ERE syntax
- `(^|[^}])\},`  matches either start of string or any char other than `}` and captures this value into Group 1 (referred to with `\1` from the replacement pattern) and then matches `},`
- `g` - replaces all occurrences.

If you just use `\1` as replacement, this will simply remove `},`, add some text if you need to replace.

Comment: @dataviews Could you please explain? The best would be to provide some test case, say, via ideone, see [the demo](https://ideone.com/8uaP7S), it works as it removes `},` only when the `}` is not preceded with another `}`.